# Convergence of events in a probability space with respect to $L^2$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Define for events $X, Y$ that $d(X,Y) = P((X-Y) \cup (Y-X)) $ = $ P(X \bigtriangleup Y) $, show that $d(X_n,X) \rightarrow 0$ if and only if $\chi_{X_n}$ converges in $L^2$ to $\chi_X$ (these are indicator functions which take on values  of 1 when in the set and 0 outside of the set).

I know how $L^2$ convergence works, but just applying the definitions here I wasn't able to get much far.  Using the hint given below, we can see that:
if $d(X_n,X) \rightarrow 0$ then $ P(X_n \bigtriangleup Y) \rightarrow 0 $ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, now we want to show $||\chi_{X_n}-\chi_{X}||_2^2 \rightarrow 0$, we notice $||\chi_{X_n}-\chi_{X}||_2^2 = \int(\chi_{X_n}-\chi_{X})^2 = \int\chi_{X_n \bigtriangleup X} = P(X_n \bigtriangleup X) \rightarrow 0$. Is that how on direction would go? Would the other direction be similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  $(\chi_A - \chi_B)^2 = \chi_{A \triangle B}$

Comment: Can you read my edit and see if it makes sense? Also can you go over explaining how you would notice this equality holds, its not obvious to me.

Comment: Your edit looks good. The point is that since $P(X_n \triangle X) = d(X_n,X)$ and $P(X_n \triangle X) = \int \chi_{X_n \triangle X} = \int (\chi_{X_n}-\chi_X)^2$, you get $\|\chi_{X_n}-\chi_X\|_2^2 = d(X_n,X)$. Therefore, one of these goes to zero if and only if both do. As for the equality of, here's the idea $\chi_A - \chi_B$ is $1$ on $A-B$, is $-1$ on $B - A$ and is $0$ elsewhere. Therefore, by squaring this, $(\chi_A - \chi_B)^2$ is $1^2=1$ on $A-B$, $(-1)^2=1$ on $B-A$, and $0$ elsewhere, but this is exactly $\chi_{A \triangle B}$.